# Open Chrome DevTools command menu with single shortcut in macOS

Tags: macos, google-chrome-devtools

On macOS, you can open the DevTools and then press Command+Shift+P to open the [command menu](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/command-menu/). But is it possible to open the command menu without having to first open the DevTools?

Comment: Can't you rebind it in settings (cog icon) -> Shortcuts on macOS?

Comment: Those shortcuts seem to apply only when the DevTools is open :(

Comment: I misunderstood this. There's no way to achieve that with just Chrome then. You'll need to create a macro in external app.

Comment: Oh ok, that's a shame. Do you know of any good apps that let you create macros for this type of scenario?

Comment: I'm not a macOS user so not quite. Look for something like AutoHotkey on Windows.

Comment: Will do - thanks for your help 